# crystal viewer disrupts the log4j configuration

Tags: log4j, crystal-reports-xi

We have JBoss 4.0.3, log4j.xml in the jboss/server/default/conf folder. We set the system property ear.config.files.location to this folder. This log4j.xml gets loaded good when the application is running. We use crystal viewer components (java reporting component) to view few reports. The moment one of this report is loaded, our logging configuration is gone.
Almost nothing comes to the log file anymore. Is there a way to track down how this happens

The moment crystal report loads, SimpleLayout class gets loaded. i wonder why?

I am seeing DomConfigurator.configure can we use it to reload the file. Or can we use DomConfigurator.configureAndWatch to load it periodically.

Any ideas will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted here solved my issue

http://scn.sap.com/thread/1273402

In case the above link does not work, I have copy-pasted the necessary information below

---

After a long search, I have found the following :
In the JRCCommunicationAdapter class, a fonction is calling Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ERROR).

So I'have made a copy of the rootLogger's level before I open the ReportClientDocument and re-set it after the open.

Level rootLevel = Logger.getRootLogger().getLevel();
...
oReportClientDocument.open (iRptName, OpenReportOptions._openAsReadOnly);

### Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(rootLevel);